# Cocoon gem showing rating for only first field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cocoon-gem

I am developing an app that allows HR Managers rate candidates based on key indicators. I use cocoon gem to add the indicators per candidate and ratyjs to add star rating. But unfortunately, the star shows only on the first field because cocoon gem generates a new id per field. How can I get my rating to show for every candidate?

Please help!

Below is a snippet of my code

```
<div id="edu-rating"></div>
 ...
<script>
$('#edu-rating').on('cocoon:after-insert').raty({
starOn: '<%= image_path('star-on.png') %>',
starOff: '<%= image_path('star-off.png') %>',
starHalf: '<%= image_path('star-half.png') %>',
path: '',
scoreName: 'interview_candidate[education]',
space: true 
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I used class instead. It worked!